# Can't load CSV File into MySql Workbench via Import Wizard

Tags: mysql, csv, utf-8, ascii, iso-8859-1

when I try to load this CSV into MySQl DB I get following error.

```
Platz;Team;Saison;Spieltag;Punkte;Sieg;Unentschieden;Niederlage;Geschossen;Bekommen;Differenz;berUnter;HeimAuswrts;Gegner;Gegnertabellenposition_Vor_Spieltag;Gegner_Gegentore;Gegnertore

1;Borussia Dortmund;1819;1;3;1;0;0;4;1;3;1;H;RB Leipzig;6;4;1
2;FC Bayern Mnchen;1819;1;3;1;0;0;3;1;2;1;H;TSG 1899 Hoffenheim;3;3;1
```

What's wrong with my CSV File? In the DB alle fields have datetype int only Team,HeimAuswrts and Gegner is varchar.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
ERROR: Import data file: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
Failed
```

Answer (score 2):

Guten tag.  You seem to be loading your CSV data, containing German-language characters, as if it contained only ASCII characters. ASCII is the ancient English-only character set used by teletype machines. If you want München loaded in ASCII, you must spell it Muenchen.

But you should try to use a more world-friendly character set (like utf-8). In the Configure Import Settings panel of the workbench's import wizard, set the encoding to utf-8 (or maybe to iso-8859-1, also known as latin-1).

Comment: Which UTF-8 collation do we use on the table? There are like a dozen of them.